# Facebook Login API Disabled -- Unable to Test Flow

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, authentication

My app access to the Facebook API has been disabled, now I cannot get the app approved because Facebook says the login process does not work. How am I supposed to have Facebook Login API work if they disable access to it? It's a very frustrating issue, because they will not re-enable access until it works and it will not work until they re-enable access.

Has anyone else dealt with this circular loop?

"We've disabled this app for violating the Facebook Platform Policies. You can continue to use it in development mode. Read more or appeal"

I've updated the app and it is working fine, the same exact code has been used before and is working. But i cannot test the login flow until the API is re-enabled.

Edit: This is the message that appears when i use Facebook login  "FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Invalid access_token, error code 43 ]"

Comment: _"You can continue to use it in development mode"_ - did you do that, put the app back into development mode?

Comment: Yes, the app is automatically set to development mode, but the version that the Facebook team uses to review is likely live, which is the only version publicly accessible.

Comment: _"but the version that the Facebook team uses to review is likely live"_ - first of all, I doubt it, and second of all, what does that have to do with _"But i cannot test the login flow until the API is re-enabled."_? You develop/test/bugfix your issues in dev mode, and then you submit for review. That is how it works for the initial app development, so why should it be different now in this scenario?

Comment: They disabled access of a live app. This app had to get the android keys reset, which led to issues with the facebook login and they disabled access before i could update the key hashes on facebook console. I have since made all the changes for this login to work properly, but it's still contingent on Facebook approving access.

Comment: how did you fix this issue?

Comment: Im having same problem.. I think the blocked is the problem.